# JS: Fail to obtain object after change of filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a list of items with anchor `a` that successfully listen to the following event:

```
$('body[data-link="media"] #media_content a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $('.page.active a')[0].innerHTML;
    var date = $('.year_sorting .filter_years').val();
    var id = $(e.currentTarget).data('media');
    window.location.href = 'http://'+basePath+'media/content/'+id+'?date='+date+'&page='+page;
})
```

However in the same page, there is a filter allowing the user to change the year filter and once changed, the following execute and append a list of items that has the exact same layout as the `a` above `$('body[data-link="media"] #media_content a')`, which supposes to listen to the above event as well. the filter event is below:

```
$('.activity.filter_years').on('change',function(){
    $('.pagination_ul').remove();
    r_year = $(this).val();
    $.get("media/getActivity",{type:'0',key:r_year}).done(function(d){
        if(d.length>0){
            $('#media_content').html('');
            var ul = '<ul class="ap pagination-sm pagination_ul"></ul>';
            $('.pagination_menu').append(ul);
            for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++){
                var p = ['',''];
                if(!d[i].event_period){
                    p = ['style="color:#8A8A8A;"','style="color:#C7C7C7;"'];
                }


                if(locale=='en'){
                    var event = $('<div class="div_media_content_f2 '+d[i].pagination+' pagination-tr"> <a href="media/content/'+d[i].event_id+'" data-media="'+d[i].event_id+'"> <div class="div_media_content_f2_3"> <span class="font12_bold">'+d[i].event_date+'</span> <div>'+d[i].event_title+'</div></div></a></div>')
                }else if(locale=='hk'){
                    var event = $('<div class="div_media_content_f2 '+d[i].pagination+' pagination-tr"> <a href="media/content/'+d[i].event_id+'" data-media="'+d[i].event_id+'"> <div class="div_media_content_f2_3"> <span class="font12_bold">'+d[i].event_date+'</span> <div>'+d[i].event_title_zh+'</div></div></a></div>')
                }else {
                    var event = $('<div class="div_media_content_f2 '+d[i].pagination+' pagination-tr"> <a href="media/content/'+d[i].event_id+'" data-media="'+d[i].event_id+'"> <div class="div_media_content_f2_3"> <span class="font12_bold">'+d[i].event_date+'</span> <div>'+d[i].event_title_cn+'</div></div></a></div>')
                }

                $('#media_content').append(event);
            }
            pagination('.pagination_ul','.pagination-tr',Math.ceil(d.length/20),false);
        }else{
            $('#div_news_content_right').html('').append('<div class="not_available">No content available</div>');
        }
    })

})
```

in which you can see the list of items are being appended into the layout by JS. However, even with the same layout `$('body[data-link="media"] #media_content a')`, such appended list of items do not listen to the `onclick` event. the above js codes are together in a separate js file apart from the html file where I tried to put the first `a` event into the html file but the new appended list of items still do not listen.

Cannot think of other work around at the moment, please help to see what would be the cause of it. Thank you.

Comment: Bind your click event again after append

Comment: You mean putting the click event code after the appends? I just tried and it didn't work either.

Comment: Can you provide the jsfiddle, i can update your code then

Comment: Thanks @JagjeetSingh, problem is solved. Thank you for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe simple try this.

```
$(document).on('click', 'body[data-link="media"] #media_content a')
```

If your element is dynamic create you should bind the click event on document and target what's element should dispatch the event.This is different to bind click only on element because the event will unbind while you remove the element.

---

**Updated:**

I'm not sure I've understand all the script you have but I try to simplify the issue.
This is the jsbin and its work correctly.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mimebav/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: Thank you @jerry_p for answering. `$(document).on('click', 'body[data-link="media"] #media_content a',function(e){` this is what i put instead of `$('body[data-link="media"] #media_content a').on('click',function(e){`, at the time i go into the page it execute such event and jump to the other page.

Comment: Sorry @jerry_p, i mean it didn't quite work. The event didn't happen at the time i click `a`, but at the time i loaded the page..

Comment: You means you don't click anything and it jump the page?

Comment: that's right, all i did was insert the url in browser, enter, it goes to the page for a second and the event executed and jump to other page.

Comment: It works now, somehow the object i stated might not be specifically enough? I changed `'#media_content a'` to `#media_content>div>a'` then it works, though seems this shouldn't make a difference to me...

Comment: @warmjaijai That's weird though I'm glad that you solved this issue.